# Number of System.out.println seems to be capped

Tags: java, bluej, system.out

I am working on a BlueJ project which outputs a lot of information, and I have run into the issue I cannot see the entirety of. I should see G0 at the top, but all I can see at the top is

```
    Cold
    Severe
    7020 hours
Dwarf
    .99 AU
    .17 Gs
    Diameter is .27 comp to earth
    Mass is .01 comp to earth
    Outer
    Very Thin
    Frozen
    Moderate
    22 hours

    Father Planet: Terran
```

The limit appears to be roughly around 200 lines. Is there any way to increase this limit?

Comment: Thanks! That solved the issue.